# Create custom collectionview with header and footer

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I want to use collection view in multiple view controller.

so I want to create separate view(collectionview with header).

now my problem is 
I have added view and also added collectionview as a subview.
I have enabled header and footer 
but I can't add any label or image in that header view.

same thing working when I add collection view in view controller

Answer (score 1):

Header view and footer view in UICollectionView must extends **UICollectionReusableView** class.

In your HeaderView and FooterView classes, in their xib you can add UIImageView or UILabel. If you don't use xib, you can add components in HeaderView (FooterView) class, in .m file.

In ViewController where you added UICollectionView, in `viewDidLoad` method you have to add this lines of code:

```
 [_collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionReusableView class] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderView"];
 [_collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionReusableView class] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter withReuseIdentifier:@"FooterView"];
 [_collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
```